# How to get filename strings from Azure DevOps artifact build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to create a script which count how many times a specific file appears in an artifact builds.
I'm trying to get the name of artifact files from Azure DevOps Rest Apis but it seems it doesn't exit any API calls to get that information.
These are the API calls I'm using to get artifact names from a specific pipeline:

1. This api get all the builds of a specific pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

2. When I get all the build-ID of that pipeline, I can start searching artifacts:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?api-version=7.0
```

Now I have all the artifacts of a specific build but I don't have idea how the get the filenames string of the artifacts. The only thing I found in Azure DevOps documentation is a REST API call to download specific files of the artifact:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&$expand={$expand}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

or

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

```
GET GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=7.1-preview.5
```

What I expect is to find a REST API that get also some information of the files inside the artifacts.

Do someone know how to get that information?

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I tried to make a post request but it seems it doesn't work.. How you set postman ?

Comment: I tested again in postman using the sample I have shared. It worked fine. You can see the screenshot I have updated in my answer. Please remember to replace with your own information in the url and body.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following API which can be captured in the network trace:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview
```

Here's the sample request body:

```
{
    "contributionIds": [
        "ms.vss-build-web.run-artifacts-data-provider"
    ],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "artifactId": {artifactId},
            "buildId": {buildId},
            "sourcePage": {
                "routeValues": {
                    "project": "{YourProjectName}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you'll get a response like this:

```
{
    "dataProviderSharedData": {},
    "dataProviders": {
        "ms.vss-web.component-data": {},
        "ms.vss-web.shared-data": null,
        "ms.vss-build-web.run-artifacts-data-provider": {
            "buildId": 1487,
            "buildNumber": "1487",
            "definitionId": 176,
            "definitionName": "test5-CI",
            "items": [
                {
                    "artifactId": 117,
                    "name": "/TestResults",
                    "sourcePath": "/TestResults",
                    "size": 0,
                    "type": "directory",
                    "items": null
                },
                {
                    "artifactId": 117,
                    "name": "/a",
                    "sourcePath": "/a",
                    "size": 0,
                    "type": "directory",
                    "items": null
                },
                {
                    "artifactId": 117,
                    "name": "/b",
                    "sourcePath": "/b",
                    "size": 0,
                    "type": "directory",
                    "items": null
                },
                {
                    "artifactId": 117,
                    "name": "/s",
                    "sourcePath": "/s",
                    "size": 988,
                    "type": "directory",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "artifactId": 117,
                            "name": "/s/README.md",
                            "sourcePath": "/s/README.md",
                            "size": 985,
                            "type": "file",
                            "items": null
                        },
                        {
                            "artifactId": 117,
                            "name": "/s/folder1",
                            "sourcePath": "/s/folder1",
                            "size": 3,
                            "type": "directory",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "artifactId": 117,
                                    "name": "/s/folder1/file1",
                                    "sourcePath": "/s/folder1/file1",
                                    "size": 3,
                                    "type": "file",
                                    "items": null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In postman:
[image]

And for your reference, this is the artifact in Azure DevOps:

[image]

Comment: This does not work.